# How can I access the value of my LiveData model in my respository

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I am working on an Android project using MVVM architecture, repositories and a Room database. So in my repository, I fetch some data from database and return the LiveData object to my ViewModel. Here is my code (very simplified):

```
public class Repository {

    private final IDao mDao;
    private OrderModel mOrderModel;
    private LiveData<OrderModel> mOrderModelLiveData;

    public Repository(Database database) {

        mDao = database.dao();
        mOrderModelLiveData= mDao.getOrderModel();

        mOrderModel = new OrderModel();
    }

    public LiveData<OrderModel> getOrderModelLiveData() {

        return mOrderModelLiveData;
    }    
}
```

As you can see I have a field called mOrderModel. So how can achieve to assign the actual value of the LiveData called mOrderModelLiveData to mOrderModel?

One option is to use LiveData's getValue() method. But this works asynchronously and can return NULL. A second option is to add a new DAO method which returns the mOrderModel directly without LiveData. But then `mOrderModel` is not updated automatically. Or do I have to use `Transformations.switchMap` maybe like this:

```
Transformations.map(mDao.getOrderModel(), new Function<LiveData<OrderModel>>() {

            @Override
            public Object apply(OrderModel orderModel) {

                mOrderModel = orderModel;
                return null;
            }
        };
```

I have seen an example, where `observeForever` is used, but I am not sure if it is a good idea to observe LiveData without a lifecycle.

My goal is to have in my repository the `mOrderModel` field set without using LiveData.

I hope I described my problem understandable.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can follow your second approach like below:

```
public class Repository {

    private final IDao mDao;
    private OrderModel mOrderModel;
    private MutableLiveData<OrderModel> mOrderModelLiveData;

    public Repository(Database database) {

        mDao = database.dao();
        mOrderModel = new OrderModel();
        mOrderModelLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void getData() {
        mOrderModel = mDao.getOrderModel(); // Your dao should return model instead of livedata
        mOrderModelLiveData.postValue(mOrderModel);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<OrderModel> getOrderModelLiveData() {

        return mOrderModelLiveData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this approach looks like what I am looking for. Thank you. But I see that the call of mDao.getOrderModel() without LiveData has to be placed in a worker thread, right?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. Better to place asynchronous operation inside ViewModel

Comment: Also you can make your `getData()` asynchronous

Comment: Hi, I think there is no problem to make ```getData()``` asynchronous, but when I call this method, the database is always queried. A better way would be (for my implementation), whenever the LiveData is updated, the OrderModel is set to the actual LiveData value automatically. How could I realize this? Thank you

Comment: Still I don't find any meaning of using model with LiveData, can you please clear your requirements?

Comment: I want to observe the LiveData object within the view to update the UI. And additionally I want to have access from the ViewModel to the OrderModel to do some validation with it within the ViewModel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206419/discussion-between-chris-p-and-md-asaduzzaman).

Answer (score 0):

```
This will be placed in your repository.

    public LiveData<OrderModel> getOrderModelLiveData() {
    MutableLiveData<OrderModel> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    service.getOrderModelLiveData().enqueue(new Callback<OrderModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OrderModel> call, Response<OrderModel> response) {
            ResponseObj body = response.body();
            if (body != null ) {
                data.postValue(body);
            } else {
                data.postValue(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MostResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            data.postValue(null);
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

But how can I transform/assign the actual value of the LiveData object (LiveData) to the "normal" object (OrderModel).

On the one hand I want to observe LiveData as usual, and on the other hand I also want to access OrderModel directly from outside of the repository .